# Manually install Open Multilingual Worldnet (NLTK)

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I am working with a computer that can only access to a private network and it cannot send instrunctions from command line. So, whenever I have to install Python packages, I must do it manually (I can't even use Pypi). Luckily, the NLTK allows my to manually download corpora (from [here](https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/)) and to "install" them by putting them in the proper folder (as explained [here](https://www.nltk.org/data.html#manual-installation)).

Now, I need to do exactly what is said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43917261):

```
>>> cane_lemmas = wn.lemmas("cane", lang="ita")
>>> print(cane_lemmas)
```

> [Lemma('dog.n.01.cane'), Lemma('cramp.n.02.cane'),
> Lemma('hammer.n.01.cane'),  Lemma('bad_person.n.01.cane'),
> Lemma('incompetent.n.01.cane')]

And to do so, I thought it would be enough to download the file "52. Open Multilingual Wordnet", unzip it in C:\nltk_data\corpora and to run the previously mentioned code after importing

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
```

However, when I run the code:

```
>>> cane_lemmas = wn.lemmas("cane", lang="ita")
>>> print(cane_lemmas)
```

I get this error:

> WordNetError: line 'es; it won brilliant victories over British frigates during the War of 1812 and is without doubt the most famous ship in the history of the United States Navy; it has been rebuilt and is anchored in the Charlestown Navy Yard in Boston  \n': not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

However, if I run:

```
>>> cane_lemmas = wn.lemmas("dog", lang="eng")
>>> print(cane_lemmas)
```

I correctly get:

> [Lemma('dog.n.01.dog'), Lemma('frump.n.01.dog'), Lemma('dog.n.03.dog'), Lemma('cad.n.01.dog'), Lemma('frank.n.02.dog'), Lemma('pawl.n.01.dog'), Lemma('andiron.n.01.dog'), Lemma('chase.v.01.dog')]

What am I doing wrong?

I am using python 3.7.4 and and nltk 3.4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be certain, can you verify your current nltk_data folder structure? The correct structure is:

```
nltk_data
+ corpora
  + wordnet
    + adj.exc
    + adv.exc
    + ...
  + omw
    + ...
    + ita
      + citation.bib
      + LICENSE
      + ...
    + ...
```

However, in most situations where the issue is due to an incorrect `nltk_data` install, NLTK will notify you that there was an issue with the install (and that you must perform e.g. `nltk.download("wordnet")` to resolve it)

I believe that in order to do what you're suggesting, you must have both `wordnet` and `omw` downloaded:

- `omw`: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/corpora/omw.zip
- `wordnet`: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/corpora/wordnet.zip

Keep in mind that NLTK now supports 2 versions of OMW (there is also `omw-1.4.`, but support for this was only added in NLTK 3.6.7). Furthermore, there are 3 versions of wordnet: `wordnet`, `wordnet2021`, `wordnet31` and `wordnet_ic`. However, I believe you should be okay with sticking just with `omw` and `wordnet`.

See https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/ for some more information on the `nltk_data` packages.