# How do I use Wordnet for Dutch? Open Multilingual Wordnet will not work?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, open-multilingual-wordnet

I'm fairly new to python, please bear with me.
I am trying to create a code that identifies the difficult words in a Dutch sentence and lists them. For this, I need to know if the Dutch words in the input have any hypernyms.
When I download Open Multilingual Wordnet, it cannot be imported through `from nltk.corpus import omw as omw` , not sure why. Should I use `nltk."some other module?"` ?
I have tried using regular Wordnet instead, and applying `lang='nld'` in different parts of the code, but this does not work.
Maybe something else is incorrect? Any help is appreciated.

```
import nltk 
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('omw')
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
#from nltk.corpus import omw as omw

input1 = input("Input difficult text: ").lower()

words = nltk.word_tokenize(input1)
word_list = [i
             for i in words
                 if i.isalnum()
                 ]

#find hypernyms for words and append in list
l = []
for x in word_list:
    hyper = (wn.synset(x).hypernyms(lang='nld'))
    l.append(hyper[0].hypernyms() if len(hyper)> 0 else '')
```

The error message is as follows on colab:
(I think this is because I moved `lang='nld'` to `hypernyms()`, instead of `wn.synset(x, lang='nld')` , though. I.e. the value error is not the main problem.)

````
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-92fedaeb123b> in <module>()
     43 l = []
     44 for x in word_list:
---> 45     hyper = (wn.synset(x).hypernyms(lang='nld'))
     46     l.append(hyper[0].hypernyms() if len(hyper)> 0 else '')
     47 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py in synset(self, name)
   1288     def synset(self, name):
   1289         # split name into lemma, part of speech and synset number
-> 1290         lemma, pos, synset_index_str = name.lower().rsplit('.', 2)
   1291         synset_index = int(synset_index_str) - 1
   1292 

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)```
````

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Updated my question to add error message.

Comment: Quite unfamiliar with NLTK, but it looks like your OMW is not installed correctly. Could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754036/manually-install-open-multilingual-worldnet-nltk

Comment: Try `print(wn.langs())` after your `import wordnet` line. That should help narrow down if omw is correctly installed. I.e. if you see 'nld' listed then the problem is not that.

Comment: Tried ```print(wn.langs())``` , it shows 'nld'